# Ruby and mysql2: Looping Until Connection is Error Free

Tags: mysql, ruby, loops, mysql2, rescue

*Context*: I am writing a simple dynamic query in Ruby using the `mysql2` gem.

Attempt:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
require "mysql2"

puts "Please enter the title of this Report:"
title = gets.chomp

Mysql2::Client.default_query_options.merge!(:as => :array)

puts "Please enter the host, username, password and database in order:"
hst = gets.chomp
user = gets.chomp
pass = gets.chomp
db = gets.chomp

begin
  mysql = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => hst, :username => user, :password => pass, :database => db)
rescue Mysql2::Error => e
    puts e.errno
    puts e.error
  retry
  puts "Error: please try again."
  puts "Enter the host, username, password and database:"
  hst = gets.chomp!
  user = gets.chomp!
  pass = gets.chomp!
  db = gets.chomp!
end

puts "Successfully accessed #{db}!"
```

*Note* that:

```
rescue Mysql2::Error => e
    puts e.errno
    puts e.error
```

works with the `mysql` gem, but:

```
rescue Mysql2::StandardError => e
    puts e.errno
    puts e.error
```

does **not** work with the `mysql2` gem.

Finally, the error in Terminal:

```
iMac:workspace guy$ ruby File.rb
Please enter the title of this Report:
title
Please enter the host, username, password and database in order:
1.2.3.4
username15
password123
db_one
File.rb:19:in `rescue in <main>': uninitialized constant Mysql2::StandardError (NameError)
Did you mean?  StandardError
    from File.rb:17:in `<main>'
```

Edit after answer: leaving `:host` as `:hst` gave me the following error:

```
2002
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql2` gem has defined `Mysql2::Error`, not `Mysql2::StandardError.

You need to rescue `Mysql2::Error`

Refer to [mysql2 Github source](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/blob/master/lib/mysql2/error.rb) for more info.

Comment: Now I receive the error:

`Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) 2002`

over and over again without being able to `Ctrl + C`.

Comment: Thats a totally different issue. Basically `mysql2` was not able to connect to MySQL server. And as you are rescuing and retrying, you see the error over and over again.

Comment: I gathered that I wasn't able to connect.  I should rephrase:  I want to know why I was unable to execute the following code again: `puts "Error: please try again."
  puts "Enter the host, username, password and database:"
  hst = gets.chomp!
  user = gets.chomp!
  pass = gets.chomp!
  db = gets.chomp!` after `retry`.

Comment: As soon as the execution hits `retry`, it jumps to `begin` and the code after `retry` is never reached.